# A Good Flash Player

Tags: software-recommendation, flash, swf

Is there any software in `ubuntu`, like `KMPlayer` (in Windows) that can play `swf` (flash files) which give us the ability to fast forward and rewind and a full track bar to change the position?

With `KMPlayer` you can play `swf` files like video files (of course in Windows).

Answer (score 1):

You can try GNU Gnash. It is as good as browser plugins and also as a standalone application.

As the description saying

> GNU Gnash is a free GPL'd SWF player. It runs as a standalone application
>    on either the desktop or embedded devices, or may be used as a plugin
>    for several popular browsers. It supports playing media from a disk or
>    streaming over a network connection.

To install it : do `sudo apt-get install gnash` in a terminal.

To install via Software-Center [click this link](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnash)

Comment: I saw gnash before. But in gnash you can't surf in a file. I mean you can't fastforward 10 seconds in `swf` file, or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

Try KMPlayer for Ubuntu. You can install it from the Software Center.

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: Not that `KMPlayer`. It is a totally different matter.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer VLC.

You need to check that a universe repository is listed in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-pulse mozilla-plugin-vlc
```

Or:

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: But `vlc` can't play `swf` files like movie files.